# How to build Spot (native Spotify client) on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: compiling, spotify, 22.04, rust

Please help me compile and install [Spot](https://github.com/xou816/spot), a native Spotify client for GNOME, on Ubuntu 22.04.

**Instructions**

Here are the instructions from [the application's GitHub page](https://github.com/xou816/spot):

> Requires Rust (stable), GTK4, and a couple other things. Also requires libadwaita: it is not packaged on all distros at the moment, you might have to build it yourself!
>
> With meson:
>
> ```
> meson target -Dbuildtype=debug -Doffline=false --prefix="$HOME/.local"
> ninja install -C target
> ```
>
> This will install a `.desktop` file among other things, and the spot executable will be put in `.local/bin` (you might want to add it to your path).
>
> To build an optimized release build, use `-Dbuildtype=release` instead.

**What I've Tried**

1. I downloaded the source code using:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/xou816/spot.git
   ```
2. I do not know how to install Rust (as a deb package) in Ubuntu.
3. I have installed `meson` and `ninja` as follows. Is this correct? Am I missing any other packages?

   ```
   sudo apt install ninja-build meson
   ```
4. I get the following error when I execute the `meson target...` command from above. How can I resolve this?

   ```
   src/meson.build:3.0: ERROR: Pkg-config binary for machine 1 not found. Giving up.
   ```

Comment: It appears that `pkg-config` isn't installed. You could try `sudo apt install pkg-config`. See [this](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install) for how to install Rust. You may need to install `libadwaita-1-dev` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install prerequisite development packages.

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository universe
   sudo apt install git pkg-config libadwaita-1-dev cmake libssl-dev libasound2-dev libpulse-dev libxml2-utils ninja-build meson rust-all
   ```
2. Download, compile, and install Spot.

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   git clone https://github.com/xou816/spot.git
   cd spot
   meson target -Dbuildtype=release -Doffline=false --prefix="/usr"
   sudo ninja install -C target
   ```
3. Optionally, remove the prerequisite development packages.

   ```
   sudo apt autoremove git pkg-config libadwaita-1-dev cmake libssl-dev libasound2-dev libpulse-dev libxml2-utils ninja-build meson rust-all
   ```

Comment: Special thanks to @cocomac for providing the tip about installing `pkg-config` and `libadwaita-1-dev` !